# Open XML file in Excel and keep string formatting (don't trim leading zero)

Tags: excel, xml, formatting

I try to open an xml file, without any special schema. So Excel creates automatically a schema based on the data, but I have several numbers with leading zeros. Excel treats them as a number and trims the leading zeros.

Is there any possibility to tell excel to treat each field as string?

Thank you

Comment: as "excel user", you can overcome this problem by pre-pending a `' ` single quote ..before a number, then it is interpreted as text, maybe you can do it, too...

Comment: ..if that not helps, maybe you can edit your post by adding some (relevant) code snippets...error messages...expected/real output.